# FlexUnit 4 examples

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flexunit, flexunit4

Is there any exemplary Flex 4 projects on github to learn FlexUnit 4 from?

There are lots of examples online, but very few go further than testing addition. I'd like to find some real-word unit tests.

Thanks!

Comment: You should look into  general TDD tutorials - once you understand how unit testing works, all you need is the FlexUnit documentation. I recommend you check out Uncle Bob's episodes on unit testing at http://cleancoders.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring ActionScript contains quite an elaborate set of FlexUnit 4 tests combined with the Mockolate mocking library.

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-actionscript